# Existence of at least one positive root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, say $f = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n c_k x^k$, such that the first $c_0$ and last $c_n$ coefficients have opposite signs. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for at least one positive $x$.

Proof. Suppose $c_0 < 0 < c_n$. It is easily seen that $f(0) = c_0$. Also,

$$f(x) = c_n x^n \Bigg(1 + \frac{c_{n-1}}{c_nx} + ...+ \frac{c_0}{c_nx^n} \Bigg)$$

So, for large enough $x$, say $x = L$, we have $f(L) \approx c_n L^n$. Also, $c_n < c_n L^n$. Thus,

$$f(0) = c_0 < 0 < c_n < f(L)$$

Since we have $f(0) < 0 < f(L)$ for $x \in [0,L]$. From Bolzano's theorem, there exist a positive $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$. $\rm{QED}$

*Calculus Volume 1 by Apostol exercise 3.11.1

Can anyone comment on my proof? Did I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: It is fine! ${} {} {} $

Comment: It looks just fine to me. You may want to point out that $\;c_n<c_nL^n\;$ would mean $\;L>1\;$ , although the "large" part may cover this. Very good.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Shashi Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general direction is good, but you may want to make the statement that $f(L)\approx c_n L^n$ more precise. To be specific, for sufficiently large $x$, the absolute value of each term in the expression $\frac{c_{n-1}}{c_nx} + ...+ \frac{c_0}{c_nx^n}$ is less than $\frac1n$. Therefore,
$$f(x) = c_n x^n \left(1+\frac{c_{n-1}}{c_nx} + ...+ \frac{c_0}{c_nx^n}\right)>c_n x^n \left(1+n\left(-\frac1n\right)\right)=0$$
You can then proceed as you did.